# Getting Highers and Same score in array

Tags: php

```
$Ascore = 30;
$Bscore = 30;
$Cscore = 20;
$Dscore = 20;

 $score = array(
            'As' => $Ascore,
            'Bs' => $Bscore,
            'Cs' => $Cscore,
            'Ds' => $Dscore
);

$match = 0;
foreach($score as $key => $val){
if($val > $match){
    $match = $val;
}
}
echo $match;
```

my intention is to find highers score that match , for example highers score = 30 ,As and Bs matched , echo out As = 30 , Bs = 30. so if any 2 of the highers score in the array and having the same highers score, echo both of them. only echo them out if they have same highers score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$scores = [
    'As' => $Ascore,
    'Bs' => $Bscore,
    'Cs' => $Cscore,
    'Ds' => $Dscore,
];
$highest = max($scores);
foreach ($scores as $key => $val)
    if ($val === $highest)
        echo $key . ' = ' . $val . ', ';
```

Alternate if the trailing comma IS an issue:

```
$highest = max($scores);
$victors = [];
foreach ($scores as $key => $val)
    if ($val === $highest)
        $victors[] = $key . ' = ' . $val;

echo implode(', ', $victors);
```

Comment: This will print a trailing comma and space, though; is that a problem?

Comment: You could just add each matching result to an array and implode them with a comma

Comment: That is a thing that you could do. I wasn't going to add it unless necessary, but as you're insisting ;) thanks!

Comment: like how ? i cant get any echo werid , let me double check, thank guys

Comment: okies i replace the $score === $highest with $val === $highest and it work, thank guys

Comment: My apologies, thank you to whoever suggested the edit. Damnit I'm incompetent ATM, didn't even do the implode :| I'm going to call it a day.

Comment: haha actually you did a big favor , thank bro , i should already figure that out using that ,but i didt.